# getApplicationContext() in a Custom List-Adapter

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, backgroundworker

I have this code that works in my Fragment Class but not in my List Adapter:

```
BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
backgroundWorker.execute();
```

When I need to put this code in my List Adapter, the 'getApplicationContext' part is "errored". How do I fix this and use this code in my List Adapter. (The class in 'Tab2'),

Comment: share your adapter code with question

Comment: Why use application context for an adapter, pass the context from where it is being initialized, and in your adapter, use standard context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can

- pass `context` to your `adapter's` constructor **OR**,
- take `context` from `views` used in your `adpater`.

> For inflating layouts *in an Activity* , you *need* `Activity` **context** not **ApplicationContext** !!

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the reference of the `ApplicationContext` to the list adapter:

```
 new ListAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), anotherArgs);
```

By the way you can get a `Context` from any View class, I'm sure your adapter has access to the parent view class for creating row item views.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass an activity context as a parameter in your adapter's constructor and assign it to local context variable.

Eg :

```
 public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<YourModelclass> {

        private ArrayList<YourModelclass> list;

        Context mContext;

 public CustomAdapter(ArrayList<YourModelclass> list, Context context) {
            this.list = list;
            this.mContext=context;

        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) { }
```

In the above code, you can use your local context and then access any methods.

This is because,

Fragment is always mapped to an activity thus, GetActivity method is accessible in the Fragment class.

The GetActivity returns an Activity context and this context has access to GetApplicationContext method

However in your adapter, GetActivity has no meaning as it has not bound to an activity or neither is its parent.

Hope this helps!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can do that for two ways

1. pass `context` to your `Adapter's` constructor from your activity or fragment **OR**,
2. take `context` from `views` used in `adpater`. you can ask for context from view directly like `viewObject.getContext().getApplicationContext()`

Also remember if you need to inflate view you will need Activity's context as application context will not work there. Every context (Activity, application,baseContext etc) has different responsibilities and provide different facilities. You must choose according to the need. 
Also this is very basic thing. you must learn basic context usage in android components.